# PHP / IIS does not interpret php code correctly -> blank page for phpinfo()

Tags: php, iis

on my Win 10 machine i would like to use PHP on IIS. I went through different tutorials to get it to work but currently when i call the index.php file i got an blank page and the response is only the content of the php file (see this in browser dev tools).

content of the file:
`

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

`
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlBtp.png)

what i have done is:

- [installed CGI under Windows features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIEdV.png)
- [php 8.1.2 x86 Non thread safe unzipped under C:\php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMeKA.png)
- php.ini adjusted like described in the tutorial(s)
- [linked the directory under environment variables to C:\php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLyaq.png)
- [set the handler mapping for php in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjxgx.png)
- [checked the fast cgi module in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnD9f.png)

I also activated the Failed Requested Trace in IIS and the outcoming log had following section:
For me it looks good, or i am wrong? If its  helpful i can post the whole .xml, but it is very large.

```xml
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>43</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-11-15T15:58:47.038Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{8000000A-0005-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="5540" ThreadID="1392"/>
  <Computer>SRV01</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{8000000A-0005-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="OldHandlerName"></Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerName">PHP_via_FastCGI</Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerModules">FastCgiModule</Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerScriptProcessor">C:\php\php-cgi.exe</Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerType"></Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="de-DE">
  <Opcode>HANDLER_CHANGED</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

Comment: To find which handler is handling your request. https://serverfault.com/questions/322943/in-iis-7-5-how-can-you-tell-which-modules-and-handler-ran-for-a-particular-requ

Comment: i updated my question with some more infos @shingo

Comment: When you see raw PHP code in HTTP response, that means you failed to configure PHP properly. If you share the complete FRT trace log, someone might tell more on what's wrong. You can also run another report to find out common issues, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi i had installed your jexus manager and run the diagnostic. it give me the hint that my php.ini file could not be parsed. So i fixed the php config and start diagnostic again -> no further errors displayed, but it didn`t work so far.

Comment: Edit the question and include the latest diagnostics report. With that, others might suggest what you can try next.

Comment: Ok, i had detect the reason why it is not working. The problem seams to be the port. the phptest website runs on port 82 and if i run  a php file in the default web site (port 80) it works. Now the big question, why??? Anybody idea?

Comment: Do you have other websites using port 82? Use failed request trace to view detailed request information, it will help you identify the problem.

Comment: @samwu I have 2 Sites running, default site with port 80 and phptest site with port 82. I already activated the request failed trace but didnt find a hint that point to the issue. It is a huge file so  i would not post it here.

Comment: Check the Request Details in the xml file to see if there is more detailed information.